# Locking a QMutex inside a destructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt4, thread-safety

I created a class to handle a shared queue in a thread-safe manner using a `QMutex` object. One of the attributes of this class is a queue of pointers, so the descructor should deallocate every object that may be present in the queue.

Should the destructor lock the mutex before deallocating the objects in the queue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should.

You call destructor from some thread (A). If at moment when that thread A starts deleting pointers from Queue your processor will start to execute instructions from another thread (B), that is trying to read something, then back some instructions from A, for example, you will receive memory corruption.

Thread safe means you always lock if you change it. And at least shared locking if you read.